# Displaying PDF from list in WebView using swift

Tags: swift, pdf, tableview

I have a list of PDF's embedded in my app. I would like to use webView to display one pdf at a time, selected from a table view controller. The example program, from Neil Smith, uses the webView to display web pages using the following code snippet from a detail view controller:

```
if let address = webSite {
    let webURL = NSURL(string: address)
    let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: webURL!)
    webView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
```

The following code snippet does what I want it to do, but only for the file "TestPDF"

```
if let pdf = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("TestPDF", withExtension: "pdf",
    subdirectory: nil, localization: nil)  {
        let req = NSURLRequest(URL: pdf)
        let webView = UIWebView(frame: CGRectMake(20,20,self.view.frame.size.width-40,self.view.frame.size.height-40))
        webView.loadRequest(req)
        self.view.addSubview(webView)
```

I would like to change this so that it selects a PDF from a list, for example:

```
pdfAddresses = [
    "TestPDF.pdf",
    "TestPDF2.pdf",
    "TestPDF3.pdf",
    "TestPDF4.pdf",
    "testPDF5.pdf"]
```

The segue code works on the webAddress list just fine:

```
if segue.identifier == "ShowAttractionDetails" {
        let detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController
            as! AttractionDetailViewController

        let myIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
        let row = myIndexPath?.row
        detailViewController.webSite = webAddresses[row!]
```

So what I don't know what to do is how to select the pdf file, based on the table view controller. I think I need to create a variable... but I'm not sure. Thank you for you suggestions.

Comment: What's the `webAddresses`?

Comment: It was a list of web addresses that the webview would bring up. See Neil Smith's work on IOS8 for the example I based this project on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is simple example for you:

**TableViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    //Your PDF list
    var pdfAddresses = [
        "TestPDF",
        "TestPDF2",
        "TestPDF3",
        "TestPDF4"]


    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return pdfAddresses.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.textLabel?.text = pdfAddresses[indexPath.row]  //Display PDF list in tableView
        return cell
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "ShowAttractionDetails" {
            let detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! AttractionDetailViewController

            let myIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
            let row = myIndexPath?.row
            //Pass selected cell title to next View
            detailViewController.webSite = pdfAddresses[row!]
        }
    }
}
```

**AttractionDetailViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class AttractionDetailViewController: UIViewController {
    //Outlet of webView but you can create it programatically too.
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
    //This will hold data which is passed from first View
    var webSite : String?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //Load selected PDF into webView.
        if let webSite = webSite {
            println(webSite)
            if let pdf = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(webSite, withExtension: "pdf", subdirectory: nil, localization: nil)  {
                let req = NSURLRequest(URL: pdf)
                webView.loadRequest(req)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Check this [SAMPLE](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=23895698677004150253) project for more Info.

Comment: Thanks! That worked and I see I have a bit more studying to do.!